# How do I make a column as wide as its content, while truncating other columns with ellipsis?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table:

```css
.myContainer {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
}

.myTable {

}

.columnA {
  max-width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.columnB {

}

.columnC {

}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <table class="myTable">
    <th>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td class="columnA">Jack Jackman</td>
      <td class="columnB">170.000</td>
      <td class="columnC">70.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="columnA">Smith Smithman</td>
      <td class="columnB">180.000</td>
      <td class="columnC">80.000</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need to get rid the fixed `max-width: 80px;` for `.columnA` without losing the ellipsis effect. Such that:

- There are no fixed widths except for the external Div.
- The table is as wide as the external Div.
- Columns B & C are as wide their content (no wrapping/overflow)
- Column A takes up the remaining width while handling text overflow with "..."

[Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sfLyzdcu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, where you add an extra div in `columnA` and set `columnB`/`columnC` to a small width.

The extra div also need to have `position: absolute`, or else it will push everything to the right.

```css
.myContainer {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.myTable {
  width: 100%;
}
.columnA {
  position: relative;
}
.columnA div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.columnB {
  width: 10%;
}
.columnC {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <table class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="columnA"><div>Jack Jackman</div></td>
      <td class="columnB">170.00</td>
      <td class="columnC">70.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="columnA"><div>Smith Smithman</div></td>
      <td class="columnB">180.00000</td>
      <td class="columnC">80.000</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good start, if there is a solution without `table-layout: fixed;`, that would be preferable. Thanks.

Comment: @latte Updated ... without `table-layout: fixed;` :)

Comment: @latte Updated .. now it does :)

Comment: @latte And next time, please ask first before undo an accepted answer, thanks